# Elimination of HCl from isomeric chlorocyclohexadienes

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, elimination

> Which of these is most easily dehydrohalogenated?
>
> [image: Chlorocyclohexadienes]
>
> **a.** 5-Chlorocyclohexa-1,3-diene (**1**)
> **b.** 3-Chlorocyclohexa-1,4-diene (**2**)
> **c.** 1-Chlorocyclohexa-1,4-diene (**3**)
> **d.** Both **1** and **3**

I encountered this question a while ago.  The given answer is option **(b)** (compound **2**). But the dehydrohalogenation of compound **1** produces benzene which has high heat of formation. So why isn't that the answer?

Comment: They both form benzene. Does that change your analysis?

Comment: @jerepierre Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

That's a fair question,

Assuming that you use a **strong base for** dehydrohalogenation you will be deprotonating the most acidic $\ce{H}$ resulting in formation of a carbanion which has the highest stability in compound number **2**

You can see that the carbanion formed in compound numer **1** will have resonance with only one of the double bond and hence will be less stable then the carbanion in the compound **2** which has resonance from both the double bond.

Mechanism can be as follow :-

[image: Mechanism]

Also;

[image: Reaction Intermediate]

Comment: I thought that extended conjugation is a better stabilizing effect than cross conjugation?